# find in line java object , how to scan all the input?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

im doing a test about findInLine object but its not working and i dont know why.
this is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("enter string: ");
    String a = null;
    String pattern ="(,)";

    if (input.findInLine(pattern) != null){

        a = input.nextLine();

    }
    System.out.println(a);
```

`enter string: (9,9)                   <---------- that is what i wrote`

this is the `output: 9)`

what i need to do if i want that the variable `a` will get all the string that i wrote like this: `a = (9,9)` and not `a = 9)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever I understood. You want to input some string and if that string gets matches to your pattern you need that to be shown in console. This will give you correct output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputScan {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a;
        System.out.print("enter string: ");
        String pattern = "\\(\\d+,\\d+\\)"; // Its regex
        // For white spaces as you commented use following regex
        // String pattern = "\\([\\s+]?\\d+[\\s+]?,[\\s+]?\\d+[\\s+]?\\)";
        if ((a = input.findInLine(pattern)) != null){
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
}
```

[Java Regex Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

[Scanner findInLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findInLine%28java.lang.String%29)

Input:

```
(9,9)
```

Output :

```
(9,9)
```

Comment: Ok i tried that it worked only if im writing (9,9) but if the user will write (9, 9) or ( 9 , 9 ) or something like that?? and what is this \\(\\d+,\\d+\\)?

Comment: @Eran Thats called `regular expression` I will provide the link for that in my answer.

Comment: This works only likt that: (9,9), in my program the user can write (9, 9 ) or ( 9,9) OR ( 9 , 9 ). i dont know what he wrotes.

Comment: @Eran I updated the answer. I also put new regex in commented section which will satisfy your need. Also take a look at regex link I provided. It will help you to understand what that line is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your brackets in the regex. Now the regex matches the comma.

Moreover, you should realize that `Scanner.findInLine()` also advances on the input.

Try

```
String pattern = "\\([0-9]*,[0-9]*\\)";
String found = input.findInLine(pattern);
System.out.println(found);
```

to verify this.

Comment: This works only likt that: (9,9), in my program the user can write (9, 9 ) or ( 9,9) OR ( 9 , 9 ). i dont know what he wrotes.